# Find the keys using the values with some conditions in a dictionary using python?

Tags: python, dictionary, key-value

I have a dictionary like this:

```
 {'1956': 21,
     '2188': 76,
     '1307': 9,
     '1305': 22,
     '2196': 64,
     '3161': 1,
     '1025': 22,
     '321': 60,
     '1959': 1,
     '1342': 7,
     '3264': 2}
```

Where every keys are unique, I want to fetch those keys from the dictionary whose values are more than 60.

The output look like:

```
  ['2188','2196']
```

I can do it using a loop iteration using **get('key')** with a **if** condition, But that is a long process, what is the shortcut to do it more efficiently ?

Comment: `[k for k, v in dict.items() if v > 60]` OR `[k for k in dict if dict[k] > 60]`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
[k for k, v in mydict.items() if v > 60]
```

Comment: Of course this will still take about the same time as a for loop, just a lot neater

Answer (score 1):

```
keyValue =  {'1956': 21,
     '2188': 76,
     '1307': 9,
     '1305': 22,
     '2196': 64,
     '3161': 1,
     '1025': 22,
     '321': 60,
     '1959': 1,
     '1342': 7,
     '3264': 2}

for key, value in keyValue.items():
    if value > 60:
        print(key)

# Or just:
print([key for key, value in keyValue.items() if value > 60])
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to achieve this without loops, and order does not matter, you can try this:

```
dc = {'1956': 21, '2188': 76, '1307': 9, '1305': 22, '2196': 64, '3161': 1, '1025': 22, '321': 60, '1959': 1, '1342': 7, '3264': 2}

dc_val = sorted(dc.values(), reverse = True)
target_index = dc_val.index(60)
keys = sorted(dc.keys(), key = lambda x: dc[x])
target_keys = keys[-target_index:]
print(target_keys)

>>> ['2196', '2188']
```

Here we want to sort the dictionary by values, and pick the index of the value 60, and get all keys corresponding to the values after that index.
So first the reversed sorted values are stored in `dc_val`, why reversed? Because in case there are multiple 60s, then it will be vital for the following method. So let's say you had 2 keys with value 60, then `dc_val` would have:

```
[76, 64, 60, 60, 22, 22, 21, 9, 7, 2, 1, 1]
```

Now `target_index` would be the first index in the list where 60 occurs, which is **2**, i.e. the **third** index.
Then `keys` holds the keys sorted (not reversed) according to their values.
Then our target_keys becomes the elements after the **third** last element, we can access this by our **target_index** like this: `keys[-target_index:]`.